# Need to Arrange Some Numbers Accordingly in the View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a tree structure suppose. I know some conditions. I would like to give an example:

```
469 & 470 results 468
472 & 473 results 471
476 & 477 results 475
479 & 480 results 478
```

This is the round 1 suppose. In the next few rounds:

```
Round 2:
  468 & 471 results 467
  475 & 478 results 474
Round 3:
  467 & 474 results 466
```

I need to arrange them as shown in image. Also I have one more thing that to arrange them I have made some ids in css so that they go in the appropriate position. So starting from the right most it should get 15 and then left to it 14, 13. I cannot post images so I am making a structure here itself:

```
469
    468
470
        467
472
    471
473
             466
476
    475
477
        474
479
    478
480
```

Now the numbers each will get is:

```
1
   9
2
       13
3
   10
4
           15
5
   11
6
       14
7
   12
8
```

Now my question is I get this things from database that these two numbers result into third. I need to write a piece of code that makes this arrangement automatic. I am getting an array of hashes for each number. Means a hash for 469, other for 470 and so on. In rails term what we call is ActiveRecord::Relation. Can anyone help me please.

More update:
I know always that 469 & 470 will results 468 and so on. Also suppose I am on 466 then it will have the detail that it has came from 467 & 474. In short it has the forward and backward both numbers. I want to run a loop on them and arrange them in the above order so that the left side schedules and right side schedules match. This can be assumed as a world cup match of any sport in which the two matches result in next match and so on. And finally I want to make a tree in my view.

Comment: in which format you are getting the results for the view? I mean an array or hash? Please share the format please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. What I have done is made a custom hash. For this I have ran a loop like this:

First took the last one i.e., in the above example it is 466. So I inserted it in hash:

```
{5 => {466}}
```

Then I know that 466 has come from 467 & 474. So I inserted these two in the same has as this:

```
{5 => {466}, 4=> {467, 474}}
```

Then for the next one I ran a loop on the hash[4] and first took the two schedules from 467 and inserted in the hash and then the two from 474 in the hash. This is how:

```
{5 => {466}, 4 => {467, 474}, 3 => {468, 471, 475, 478}}
```

and so on. And then in the view I looped on the hash according to the key and arranged them in the view. Suppose the hash is s. Then:

```
(4).downto(1).each do |i|
  s[i].each do |x|
   #code to display here
  end
end
```

Hope this helps anyone else too if they need to do the same thing.